# Converting binary data in string to char

Tags: c++, char, winsock, bitset

So I have some data I convert from packet to string, in binary (datagram):

```
std::string Packet::packetToString()
{
    //packing to one bitset
    std::bitset<208> pak(std::string(std::bitset<2>(type).to_string() + std::bitset<64>(num1).to_string() + std::bitset<64>(num2).to_string() + std::bitset<64>(num3).to_string() + std::bitset<4>(state).to_string() + std::bitset<4>(id).to_string() + "000000")); 
    std::string temp;
    std::bitset<8> tempBitset(0);
    for (int i = pak.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {   
        tempBitset[i % 8] = pak[i];
        if (i % 8 == 0)
        {
            char t = static_cast<char> (tempBitset.to_ulong());
            temp.push_back(t);
        }
    }
    return temp;
}
```

Then I want to convert this string to char array (in this case `char buffer[26];`) and send it with `SendTo("127.0.0.1", 1111, buffer, 26);`

What's the problem:

```
Packet pak1(... data I input ... );
string packet;
packet = pak1.packetToString();
char buffer[26];
strcpy_s(buffer, packet.c_str());
```

Data send with this array seems to be erased in case `0x00(NULL)` appears. This is caused by c_str() i guess. How can I deal with this? :)

Answer (score 0):

`strcpy()` and `strcpy_s()` copy null terminated c-strings.  So indeed, if there's any 0x00 char in the `c_str()` the copy will end.

Use [`std::copy()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy) to copy the full data, regardless of the any 0x00 that you might encounter:

```
copy (packet.begin(), packet.end(), buffer);   // hoping packet.size()<26
```

or with [`copy_n()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy_n):

```
copy_n (packet.begin(), 26, buffer);   // assuming that packet is at least 26 bytes
```